# Branch link not capturing data in app, it only works if opens through the safari browser

Tags: swift, deep-linking, ios14, branch.io, ios-universal-links

The link doesn't capture data when I tap and opens the app

```
let branch = Branch.getInstance()
branch.initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions) { params, error in
            
    guard error == nil else { return }
    guard let userDidClick = params?["+clicked_branch_link"] as? Bool else { return }
            
     if userDidClick {
         guard let params = params as?  [String: AnyObject] else { return }
         print("deep link data: ", params)
         guard let type = params[kType] as? String else { return }
                
        }
}
```

When tap the link directly(from WhatsApp/slack/skype) it opens the app directly and I receive

`[AnyHashable("+clicked_branch_link"): 0, AnyHashable("+is_first_session"): 0]`

When the same link opens in safari it redirects to the app then I get proper params

`[AnyHashable("~creation_source"): 0, AnyHashable("+click_timestamp"): 1618546463, AnyHashable("~id"): 900551511xxx37328, AnyHashable("+match_guaranteed"): 0, AnyHashable("$one_time_use"): 0, AnyHashable("+clicked_branch_link"): 1, AnyHashable("region"): XX, AnyHashable("$ios_passive_deepview"): branch_passive_default, AnyHashable("+is_first_session"): 0, AnyHashable("type"): wallet, AnyHashable("$matching_ttl_s"): 7200, AnyHashable("~referring_link"): https://xxxxxx.app.link/8KxKoxmHGeb]`

why I am facing this different behavior? I have gone through the branch documentation 3-4 times. nothing is missing but I don't know why I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my AppDelegate class, my delegate method was like this which was depreciated

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void)
```

I just changed it to like this and it works now

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void)
```

Comment: It’s good you solved it, but this answer is not related to the question, which provided none of that code.

Comment: yes @matt you are right actually my original problem was not in branch SDK but it was native apple's method depreciation